# Could not find module `Crypto.Hash.SHA1' in Haskell in Visual Studio Code

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

I want to run my Haskell program in the terminal of Visual Studio Code, but when I try to do this I get this error back:

```
Could not find module `Crypto.Hash.SHA1'

        Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
       |
    14 |     import Crypto.Hash.SHA1
       |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to install the __package__ that includes the __module__ `Crypto.Hash.SHA1`.  A module with this name might be included in many packages, but you probably want to install the `cryptohash` package.  As for how to install packages, that varies tremendously by your setup.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I saw that I had to use Cabal install cryptonite. But now I've got another problem. It says Could not load module `Crypto.Hash.SHA1' it is a hidden module in the package `cryptonite-0.26'. How can I solve this?

Comment: I didn't mention cryptonite precisely because it does not expose said module.  You need to install a package that _does_ expose the module you want - such as the cryptohash package I suggested. There is no reasonable accessing of a hidden module from a package.

Comment: Or you can use the sha1 implementation from the cryptonite modules via `Crypto.Hash` and `Crypto.Hash.Algorithms`, but I had figured you didn't want to change the code you already have that probably assumes the cryptohash api.